# Не получается нормально разместить текст в диалоге загрузки картинки

Tags: дефект, дизайн

С размещением текста в диалоге загрузки картинки возникли проблемы. Подробнее в:

There are some problems with text placing in image upload dialog. For more details see:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/613586/178988

[image: Скриншот / Screenshot]

Comment: Крутой багрепорт. )

Comment: Может текущий вопрос вообще надо дропнуть?

Comment: @älёxölüt, задубликатил