# Некорректно размещается предпросмотр картинки

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Загружаю картинку, например, [синий прямоугольник 1024*768](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twfcz.png).
Как видно на скриншоте, превью вылазит за пунктирную рамку:

Upload an image, for example [blue rectangle 1024*768](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twfcz.png).
On the screenshot you can see that preview gets out of the dashed area:

[image: Screenshot]

PS: Этот баг опубликован до каких либо исправлений по
This bug is posted before any changes related to
[Не получается нормально разместить текст в диалоге загрузки картинки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4526/178988)

Comment: Я об этом уже [отписывался](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289418/339911) на мете мет :)