# Не получается нормально разместить текст в диалоге загрузки картинки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

> [image] [image] [image]
>
> Этот вопрос написан на двух языках в соответствии с правилами публикации деффектов на мете. Этот вопрос не на мете, поскольку там нет сниппетов.
>
> This question is written in two languages according to rules of publising bugs on meta. It isn't asked on meta as there are no snippets there.

Сниппеты-примеры стоит смотреть <kbd>На всю страницу</kbd>.
Please, look snippets with examples as <kbd>Full page</kbd>.

## Problems with placing text in Upload Image dialog

[Хотим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4372/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/4378#4378) поместить следующий текст в форму загрузки картинки:
We [want](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4372/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/4378#4378) to place following text to the upload image form:

```
**Перетащите сюда изображение** **или кликните для выбора файла** (не более 2 мегабайт)
```

но получается ужасно, т. к. текст начинает вылазить за пределы блока:
but it looks bad because text gets out of the block:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/all.css?v=b47e24eaf2e8">

<div class="wmd-prompt-background" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 1001; opacity: 0.5; height: 2805px; left: 0px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div class="modal image-upload wmd-prompt-dialog auto-center" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; top: 543.5px; left: calc(50% - 200px); height: auto;">

<form action="/upload/image?https=true" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-close">×</div>

    <div class="modal-content">
        <input type="hidden" name="fkey" value="e526c50837f7dac644a33b0afa9cc726">
        <div class="modal-dropzone">
            <div class="modal-dropzone-default tab-page" style="display: block;">
                <div class="modal-dropzone-img">
                    <input class="modal-input-file user-input" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" value="">
                </div>
                <p><b>Перетащите сюда изображение</b> <b>или кликните для выбора файла</b> (не более 2 мегабайт)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-dropzone-preview tab-page" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-options">
                <div class="modal-options-default tab-page" style="display: block;">
                    Вы также можете использовать <a href="#">ссылку из сети</a>.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-options-url tab-page" style="display: none;">
                    Ссылка из интернета
                    <input class="modal-input-url user-input" type="text" name="upload-url" placeholder="http://example.com/image.png" value="">
                    <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                    <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Отмена</a>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-options-preview tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Отменить и добавить другое изображение</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-uploading tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <p>Загружается<img class="ajax-loader" src="/content/img/progress-dots.gif" title="загрузка…" alt="загрузка…"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-error tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <span class="modal-options-error-message"></span>
                <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Закрыть</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-toobig tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <span class="modal-options-error-message">Изображение слишком большое (более 2 мегабайт)</span>
                <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Отмена</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
    <p class="modal-notice">
        на платформе <a class="icon-imgur-white" href="https://imgur.com/"></a>
        Пользовательское содержимое попадает под действие лицензии <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">cc by-sa 3.0 с указанием ссылки на источник</a> <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy/">(политика относительно содержимого)</a> 
    </p>

        <div class="modal-cta">
            <input type="submit" class="modal-cta-submit btn" value="Добавить картинку" disabled="">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<iframe style="display: none;" src="about:blank" id="upload-iframe-1484167103530" name="upload-iframe-1484167103530"></iframe></div>
```

[image: Скриншот / Screenshot]

Comment: А на Meta.SE интересно, есть сниппеты?

Comment: Вопрос не на Мете разработчики не увидят. Его необходимо перенести на Мету.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've adjusted the CSS for the image upload dialog, so the lines will fit better.

This will be with you in the next release (after rev. 2017.3.14.25408)

---

Обновил CSS для диалога загрузки изображения, так что теперь линии будут соответствовать.

Обновления вступят в силу со следующей сборкой.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что по всему диалогу распиханы фиксированные размеры в пикселях:
The problem is that all over the dialog there are a lot of constant sizes in pixels for English version:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/all.css?v=b47e24eaf2e8">

<div class="wmd-prompt-background" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 1001; opacity: 0.5; height: 1531px; left: 0px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div class="modal image-upload wmd-prompt-dialog auto-center" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; top: 552px; left: calc(50% - 200px); height: auto;">

<form action="/upload/image?https=true" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-close">×</div>

    <div class="modal-content">
        <input type="hidden" name="fkey" value="e526c50837f7dac644a33b0afa9cc726">
        <div class="modal-dropzone">
            <div class="modal-dropzone-default tab-page" style="display: block;">
                <div class="modal-dropzone-img">
                    <input class="modal-input-file user-input" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" value="">
                </div>
                <p><b>Drag and drop or click here</b> to upload your image (max 2 MiB)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-dropzone-preview tab-page" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-options">
                <div class="modal-options-default tab-page" style="display: block;">
                    You can also provide a <a href="#">link from the web</a>.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-options-url tab-page" style="display: none;">
                    Link from the web
                    <input class="modal-input-url user-input" type="text" name="upload-url" placeholder="http://example.com/image.png" value="">
                    <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                    <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-options-preview tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Cancel and add another image</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-uploading tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <p>Uploading<img class="ajax-loader" src="/content/img/progress-dots.gif" title="loading..." alt="loading..."></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-error tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <span class="modal-options-error-message"></span>
                <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Close</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-toobig tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <span class="modal-options-error-message">Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MiB)</span>
                <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
    <p class="modal-notice">
        Powered by <a class="icon-imgur-white" href="https://imgur.com/"></a>
        User contributions licensed under <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required</a> <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy/">(content policy)</a>
    </p>

        <div class="modal-cta">
            <input type="submit" class="modal-cta-submit btn" value="Add picture" disabled="">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<iframe style="display: none;" src="about:blank" id="upload-iframe-1484166277079" name="upload-iframe-1484166277079"></iframe></div>
```

Было бы лучше использовать нормальный поток внутри диалога и позволить элементам  занимать необходимое пространство. Я использую имеющиеся css-селекторы, но добавляю в начало `html`, чтобы повысить специфичность по сравнению с их версиями в коде.

It would be better to use normal flow inside of the dialog to allow elements take the space they need. I'm using original css-selectors, but prepend them via `html` to increase specificity. No any changes in markup.

```css
html .modal.image-upload .modal-dropzone-default .modal-dropzone-img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 73px auto 10px;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}

html .modal.image-upload .modal-dropzone-default p {
  margin: 0;
}

html .modal.image-upload .modal-dropzone-default,
html .modal.image-upload .modal-dropzone-preview {
  min-height: 246px;
  height: auto;
}

/* And to keep same size when image is added */

.modal-dropzone-default[style*="display: none"] { /* hide via visibility, not display */
  display: block !important;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.modal-dropzone {
  position: relative;
}

html .modal.image-upload .modal-dropzone-preview {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/all.css?v=b47e24eaf2e8">

<div class="wmd-prompt-background" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 1001; opacity: 0.5; height: 2805px; left: 0px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div class="modal image-upload wmd-prompt-dialog auto-center" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; top: 543.5px; left: calc(50% - 200px); height: auto;">

<form action="/upload/image?https=true" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-close">×</div>

    <div class="modal-content">
        <input type="hidden" name="fkey" value="e526c50837f7dac644a33b0afa9cc726">
        <div class="modal-dropzone">
            <div class="modal-dropzone-default tab-page" style="display: block;">
                <div class="modal-dropzone-img">
                    <input class="modal-input-file user-input" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" value="">
                </div>
                <p><b>Перетащите сюда изображение</b> <b>или кликните для выбора файла</b>  
(не более 2 мегабайт)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-dropzone-preview tab-page" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-options">
                <div class="modal-options-default tab-page" style="display: block;">
                    Вы также можете использовать <a href="#">ссылку из сети</a>.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-options-url tab-page" style="display: none;">
                    Ссылка из интернета
                    <input class="modal-input-url user-input" type="text" name="upload-url" placeholder="http://example.com/image.png" value="">
                    <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                    <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Отмена</a>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-options-preview tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Отменить и добавить другое изображение</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-uploading tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <p>Загружается<img class="ajax-loader" src="/content/img/progress-dots.gif" title="загрузка…" alt="загрузка…"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-error tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <span class="modal-options-error-message"></span>
                <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Закрыть</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-options-toobig tab-page" style="display: none;">
                <span class="modal-options-error-message">Изображение слишком большое (более 2 мегабайт)</span>
                <span class="modal-options-separator">|</span>
                <a class="modal-options-cancel" href="#">Отмена</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
    <p class="modal-notice">
        на платформе <a class="icon-imgur-white" href="https://imgur.com/"></a>
        Пользовательское содержимое попадает под действие лицензии <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">cc by-sa 3.0 с указанием ссылки на источник</a> <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy/">(политика относительно содержимого)</a> 
    </p>

        <div class="modal-cta">
            <input type="submit" class="modal-cta-submit btn" value="Добавить картинку" disabled="">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<iframe style="display: none;" src="about:blank" id="upload-iframe-1484167103530" name="upload-iframe-1484167103530"></iframe></div>
```

PS: Этот код НЕ исправляет [соседнюю проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4527/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8).
PS: This code does NOT fix [the other issue](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4527/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8).